# Localize ASPX Markup not work

Tags: asp.net, localization, markup

1. Create a file resources: "Master".
2. Put it in App_GlobalResources dir,
3. Add key - Menu_Contact.
4. Create another file resources: "Master.he".
5. Add key - Menu_Contact.
6. Set thread culture to "he-IL".

   ```
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
       (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)Session["Calture"];
   ```
7. Add markup to aspx file:

Here is the markup and line of test:

```
<a href="#">
    <% Response.Write(Resources.Master.Menu_Contact); %>
     <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%$Resources:Master,Menu_Contact%>'></asp:Label>
</a>
```

The first option work, The markup not.
What is wrong?

Comment: Can you specify where you are setting culture (in which event). You should set it in 'InitializeCulture'

Answer (score 0):

That was my problem. I fixed it. 
Now I set the culture on InitializeCulture and it's work!